# Is there a postman plug-in for automated testing in on-premise tfs build agent?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, automated-tests, build-process, postman

The postman chrome extension https://www.getpostman.com is a well known test client for testing REST APIs. I know that they released a command line tool called "newman" (currently at version 2.1.1 and can be installed using npm).

I am wondering if any body try to use this command line tool for testing REST APIs from automated testing step in on-premise TFS build agent (assuming API server environment is already setup).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We are using TFS 2015 Update 2.RC2.2

Comment: @Malik
With Newman you can create a junit XML result file. By adding an addtional step "Publish Test Results" to the build definition, you can public the result file to tfs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested in TFS 2015.2, it's easy to invoke newman tool in vNext build. 
You only need to add two build steps: `npm` and `Command Line`:

[image]

[image]

In my example, I get a list of options of newman (newman -h). You can also test other options in this article: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman

Comment: What is vNext build?

Comment: It's a new build system invoked in TFS 2015, you may check this blog to get some knowledge of the two build system: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1177/new-build-features-visual-studio-online-tfs-2015

Comment: where does it publish results?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT tried to reproduced what you did, keep getting error 'File not found: newman'. When specifying full path in tool parameter for Command-Line step (C:\Windows\....\newman), get the error 'specified executable is not a valid application for this os platform'. Any idea ?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT updated my TFS installation to latest update solve my problem, sorry to bother